# Flatten Parent Child Hierarchy in Excel (using formula or VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-365

I want to flatten Parent Child Hierarchy in Excel. For example:

[image]

If my original data is in blue, the destination I want to change is the orange area.
How can I use VBA or Excel formula to resolve it?

Comment: Can a child be present more than once? Can you have recursive cases?

Comment: Yes, a child can be presented more than one time sir. 

I know the recursive function, but it's not enough to meet my requirement :(

Comment: With "recursion" I mean can you have something like "a-b", "b-k1", "k1-a".

Comment: Oh no sir . You can image that Col 1 is Manager and Col 2 is Employee sir. :D

Comment: So what was your attempt(s)? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @P.b : what do u mean sir?

Comment: I mean, there's a difference between asking to help and asking to do it for you.

Comment: Of course both, sir, but I saw your comment below. Thanks for your kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably less efficient than Jos' version, but I haven't been able to test that yet (not behind a laptop).

This version is solely formula:

```
=DROP(
      REDUCE("",
             SORT(
                  REDUCE("",
                         MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(Table3)),
                         LAMBDA(x,
                                REDUCE(x,SEQUENCE(ROWS(UNIQUE(Table3[Col 1]))+1),
                                LAMBDA(a,b,                                
                                       TEXTJOIN("|",1,a,XLOOKUP(TEXTAFTER(a,"|",-1,,,a),                                  
                                                                Table3[Col 2],                                  
                                                                Table3[Col 1],                                                    
                                                                "")))))),
                  LAMBDA(a,b,                     
                     LET(c,TEXTSPLIT(b,"|"),
                         d,COUNTA(c),
                         VSTACK(a,TEXTJOIN("|",1,INDEX(c,,SEQUENCE(,d,d,-1)))))))),
      LAMBDA(a,b,
         LET(c,TEXTSPLIT(b,"|"),
             d,COUNTA(c),
             IFERROR(
                     VSTACK(a,
                            IF(SEQUENCE(,d)=d,INDEX(c,,d),"")),
                     "")))),
      2)
```

[image]

It takes all unique values from the table (Table3 in my example) and iterates from looking up the value in the child column `Col 2` and return it's parent `Col 1` and look that result up until it can't find any parent to the value.

This results in a chain from child up to the master parent. To be able to sort the results in a proper manner, this result needs reversed (master parent to latest child) and sort this. Than only show the last value per row.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Oh my sir, you are incredible.

Comment: Hello sir, can I ask 1 question?
I dont understand the code:
TEXTJOIN("|",1,a,XLOOKUP(TEXTAFTER(a,"|",-1,,,a),                                  
                                                                Table3[Col 2],                                  
                                                                Table3[Col 1],                                                    
                                                                ""))
why the "a" exists 2 times in 2 function TEXTJOIN and TEXTAFTER? I dont understand clearly how 2 function works in your code.

Comment: It's used inside REDUCE, which is a LAMBDA helper. `a` starts off as the mapped value of `x`, so the 1st value of `UNIQUE(TOCOL(Table))` (also being string `"a"`), next 2nd, etc. REDUCE starts off with that value and calculates the result. (for string `y` it will lookup `y` in `Col2` and return value `z` from `Col1`. This result is combined with the previous result using textjoin, so `TEXTJOIN("|",1,"y","z")` results in `y|z`. Next it lookups up the last string after `|` being `z` returning `g`, combined with previous result `y|z` makes `y|z|g`. Hope that makes it understandable.

Comment: This is to picture what happens: 

left column is the initial values, next it looks up the last value after `|` from the previous result, etc.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX6Je.png

Answer (score 2):

First, add an additional row to your table such that each entry in *Col 1* appears in *Col 2*. Effectively, this means ensuring that even the person at the very top of the hierarchy nevertheless appears as a 'child', i.e., they are their 'own manager', if you like. In your example, this would entail an additional row with "a" in both *Col 1* and *Col 2*.

Then add your table to the `Data Model` and open `Power Pivot`. Create a new `Calculated Column` within Power Pivot, called *Hierarchy*, with the following formula:

```
=PATH(Table1[Col 2],Table1[Col 1])
```

(which assumes that the table you added to the Data Model is named *Table1*).

You can then return to the worksheet and enter this formula somewhere:

```
=LET(
    ζ, "ThisWorkbookDataModel",
    ξ, "[Table1].[Hierarchy].Children",
    ω, CUBESET(ζ, ξ),
    φ, CUBERANKEDMEMBER(ζ, ω, SEQUENCE(CUBESETCOUNT(ω))),
    λ, MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(φ),
        MAX(MAP(φ, LAMBDA(κ, ROWS(TEXTSPLIT(κ, , "|"))))),
        LAMBDA(α, β, IFERROR(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(φ, α, 1), , "|"), β), ""))
    ),
    MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(λ),
        COLUMNS(λ),
        LAMBDA(δ, ε, LET(μ, INDEX(λ, δ, ε), IF(δ = XMATCH(μ, INDEX(λ, , ε)), μ, "")))
    )
)
```

To see the results of any changes you make to *Table1*, you will need to go to `Data/Refresh All`.

Comment: Thank sir, it's a good idea. But when I try to use PATH function in power pivot, it did not work properly. By the way, thanks for your supporting

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why did the `PATH` function "not work properly"? Did you get an error? If so, what error?

Comment: @JosWoolley Sir, fantastic, I have tested this and works great. Both the solutions worked. But learnt something new function called `CUBESET()` , `CUBERANKEDMEMBER()` & `CUBESETCOUNT()`

Comment: I assume why it has not worked for OP, because they might have not added the additional row, Sir may I ask, so does that mean that for each `Parent` an additional row is to be added everytime?

Comment: @JosWoolley: 
Dear sir, 
I follow your guide :
1. I adding "a" in the column 2 to be sure that "the person at the very top of the hierarchy nevertheless appears as a 'child'"
and it worked well now. 
But may be I have to learn about LET function , because I am stuck in LET. 
Thanks for your support sir!

Comment: But ""[Table1].[Hierarchy].Children"," what does it mean sir?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya You need to ensure that each entry in Col 1 appears in Col 2. In most situations this is likely to mean one additional role only. If we are talking about an employee hierarchy, for example, it is quite likely that there will be a just a single person at the top of the hierarchy (i.e. there will be one person who doesn't have a manager).

Comment: @ANĐỗ `[Table1].[Hierarchy].Children` is a means of referencing all distinct entries within the *Hierarchy* column.

Comment: @JosWoolley : I follow your guide but LET function can not run. It is #N/A sir:
=LET(
    a, "ThisWorkbookDataModel",
    b, "[Table13].[Hierarchy].Children",
    c, CUBESET(a, b),
    d, CUBERANKEDMEMBER(a, c, SEQUENCE(CUBESETCOUNT(c))),
    e, MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(d),
        MAX(MAP(d, LAMBDA(e, ROWS(TEXTSPLIT(e, , "|"))))),
        LAMBDA(f,g, IFERROR(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(d, f, 1), , "|"), g), ""))
    ),
    MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(e),
        COLUMNS(e),
        LAMBDA(x,y, LET(z, INDEX(e, x, y), IF(δ = XMATCH(z, INDEX(e, , y)), z, "")))
    )
)

Answer (score 0):

It seemed intuitive to me that there should be a fairly short recursive solution to this but it has taken me a while to puzzle it out. Here is the resulting function:

```
BOMM(Parent,level,Range1,Range2)

=IF(
    COUNTIF(Range1, Parent) = 0,
    hReplace({"", "", "", ""}, Level, Parent),
    REDUCE(
        hReplace({"", "", "", ""}, Level, Parent),
        FILTER(Range2, Range1 = Parent),
        LAMBDA(a, c, VSTACK(a, BOMM(c, Level + 1, Range1, Range2)))
    )
)
```

[image]

Uses a helper function

```
hReplace(array,pos,with)

=LET(seq, SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(array)), IF(seq = pos, with, array))
```