# Draw tree structure diagram from excel data

Tags: excel, office365, ms-office

I have MS Excel data in below format, second is generated form first that can be done in an automated way.

[image]

And I want something below to be created from this excel data

[image]

I tried Hierarchy diagram in MS Excel but that's not fulfilling my objective. Any native or non-native solution is well appreciated.

Comment: Where is the connection BE? If your example is incorrect then it won’t help.

Comment: Whats Connection BE?

Comment: It is in you own list, after node B Child D and before Node C Child E. Worrying if you missed it.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed it in the picture. Sorry about that. Updated now

Comment: Maybe have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76627369/flatten-parent-child-hierarchy-in-excel-using-formula-or-vba/76689857#76689857